# Accessing variables of objects stored within a vector

Tags: java, variables, vector

I have a class called Coordinate, and am building a vector of these coordinate objects.  Here's what the Coordinate class looks like - it's pretty simple:

```
    class Coordinate {
      public int x;
      public int y;

      // constructor
      public Coordinate(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
      }
}
```

My question is, after making a vector holding several instances of this class, how would I access the x or y values of a Coordinate object at a given index of the vector?
As an example:

```
v = new Vector<Coordinate>();
Coordinate a = new Coordinate(2, 3);
Coordinate b = new Coordinate(1, 4);
v.add(a);    
v.add(b);
```

How could I access the y value of the object at index0 of the vector and compare it to the y value of the object at index1?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The get method of the Vector returns the actual object in the vector.  So here is how you would compare the y values:

```
if (v.get(0).y == v.get(1).y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `elementAt()` method to get a reference to the contained object, then access its `y` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, you can reach it via the method `get(int)` of `Vector`:

```
boolean result = v.get(0).y == v.get(1).y;
```

In such cases, I suggest you to refer to [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). Also consider encapsulating your fields for data protection.